# extract line if value in first column matches and value in second column not matches in another file in bash

Tags: bash

I have 2 different files that look like this

```
 61435320        rs10000085
 12984967        rs10000091
 32039123        rs10000150
```

and this:

```
 61435320        rs12958
 12984967        rs10000091
 32039123        rs37892
```

I would like to extract only those rows which match the first field but do NOT match the second field.

So, my desired output would look like (I only want the first field):

```
61435320
32039123
```

I've tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879754/awk-comparing-2-columns-of-2-files-and-print-common-lines/879760#879760) on Ask Ubuntu but, unfortunately, it is not working for me (I guess it is not exactly what I'm looking for).

Comment: Whoever has downvoted... could please explain why? I'm quite new here and I'd like to know how to things properly! Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your files are called `a` and `b`, you can do it like this:

```
join a b | awk '{if ($2!=$3){print $1}}'
```

If your files are not sorted properly, join may have issues. You can sort them like this:

```
join <(sort a) <(sort b) | awk '{if ($2!=$3){print $1}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Only with awk :

```
awk -v'f=file2' '{if((getline b<f)>0)$0=$0 b}$1==$3 && $2 != $4{print $1}' file1
```